# how can i override default pinch zoom in osmdroid?

Tags: android, android-mapview, zooming, osmdroid

I m using [Osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) to create an offline map

Now, i want to implement my own pinch to zoom functionality for offline maps

When user uses pinch, i would like to zoom in/ zoom out to only a particular zoom level and not increment/ decrement zoom level by 1

Is there a way to do it? how can i go about this ?

**P.S : yes, there are zoom controls, but i would like to make zooming feature more intuitive**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dealt with a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583281/pinch-to-zoom-with-osmdroid/7592104#7592104), and provided the code for custom functionality on pinch. So basically, expanding on what I had in the answer, just basically do:

```
int currentZoomLevel = mOsmv.getController().getZoomLevel();
if (currentZoomLevel < (mOsmv.getControler().getMaxZoomLevel()) - 2) 
    mOsmv.getController().setZoomLevel(currentZoomLevel + 2);
```

That is just an example of increasing the zoom level by 2, instead of just 1. I also wrote the code above from memory, so I'm not 100% sure if you call `getController()` to get the current and maximum zoom level, but I'm pretty sure that's it. `mOsmv`, just in case you don't get it, is an instance of the osmdroid map.

Comment: thanks for the link , i shall implement that by monday, basically i m looking to make changes in Osmdroid's `mapview.java` so that i can make a new jar file

Comment: No problem! And remember to mark as the correct answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to do this will be to extend  MapView.

Overriding `setZoomLevel` looks like one option but I don't think it will work.  As I belive the code needs to be writen in a `this.setZoomLevel` style which it is not consistantly doing.

I think you should be able to override `selectObject` which looks like the place where a pinch trigers a call `setZoomLevel`

You will need to check the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/views/MapView.java) to see how to make the nessasary modifications