# two finger or pinc zoom to mapview in osmdroid

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview, multi-touch, osmdroid

I need help
I'm trying to zoom to mapview by getting users multi touch points (firstly 2 finger touch)
I know there is setMultiTouchControls() function but this is not what I want to do.

I tried to explain with a picture :) it was easier than writting;

The black bold arrows show the fingers' movement directions.
The same situation can be considered for opposite directions.(zoom in)

[image: osmdroid mapview multitouch]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583281/pinch-to-zoom-with-osmdroid/15159512#15159512 there is an example here but it not what I want to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, In osmdroid 3.0.10 this feature had been implemented.

```
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
```

Comment: You should write these: _mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); _mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

Comment: thanks puya. actually in previous versions you have to do the same thing for enabling multitouch functionality but the issue I had was not about how to enabling, it is I think clear in the question.