# Osmdroid and Pinch

Tags: android, zooming, openstreetmap, osmdroid, pinch

I'm developing an app using osmdroid (3.0.8).
When I zoom using two fingers in and out, the zoom starts from the center of the map, not from  the middle of the two fingers (using `MapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);`). I've tried to implement the pinch ([pinch](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)) but with bad results. 
I've read other similar questions but without finding a good solution.

Note: I MUST use OSM, and not other solutions

Comment: Are you implementing it with something like [this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847) ?

Comment: Not sure if you see [flickering as well](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=320&can=1&q=pinch%20to%20zoom).

Comment: @Sam i also use the osmdroid.but after use this i got this type error in every time.Unfortunately,System UI has Stopped.i can't remove the app from device.means device has been hang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Osmdroid 3.0.10 includes support for zooming at the location you pinched at.

The samples also include a two-finger rotation gesture overlay if that is something you are interested in trying.

Comment: please, can you provide the links about that?
I only found 3.0.9 and tested it: no pinch between fingers.

Comment: There is no 3.0.10 release yet so you will have to build from source. Source can be found on the osmdroid google code page [www.osmdroid.com](http://www.osmdroid.org). We will probably push a new release soon.

Comment: @kurtzmarc Was this included in the 3.0.10 release? That is what I am using, and the pinch zoom behavior seems to still zoom relative to the center of the map.

Comment: It was included in the 3.0.10 release and I just checked the sample app and when I pinch the corner of the map it zooms from the pinch point as intended not the center.

Comment: @kurtzmarc The issue I am trying to address is when I pinch to zoom everything goes well until I release the pinch. At that point, the map moves a bit. When you release your fingers, does the map stay still?

Comment: Note that as you pinch you are "in-between" zoom levels. So when you release, it will snap-to the closest zoom level. See [Issue 460](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=460) for progress on implementing in-between/floating point zoom levels.